Material design icons
I want to fill a DevExtreme DxSelectBox with icons.
I was wondering if there is a way to use the entire material design icon list as my DxSelectBox datasource (without me copying every icon one by one of course)
I was searching but i didnt find a single thing.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
